# Stored Procedure cant detect SET?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

im trying to make a Stored Procedure that reads different .dbf files every time i execute it, making a dynamic Stored Procedure. problem is, im not that good in sql yet and im having errors.  this is the error:

`Procedure or Function 'readDBF' expects parameter '@sql', which was not supplied.`

i know that missing something and/or making something that makes the Stored Procedure not understand but please can someone point in in he right direction?

this is the code:

`

```
USE devSSIS 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'VFPOLEDB', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE readDBF (
@path nvarchar(1000),
@name nvarchar(50),
@sql varchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
set @sql = 'select * from openrowset(''VFPOLEDB.1'', ''' + @path +'''; ''; '', ''select * from ''' + @name + ''')'
END
exec @sql
GO
```

`

im using sql 2005 btw

Comment: You have declared `@sql` as a parameter on the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement, so it has to be sent when the procedure is invoked. Given that you set the value of `@sql` yourself, you need to remove it from the parameter list and instead use a `DEFINE` statement for it.

Comment: The error is in your call (which you didn't show). You likely have `EXEC readDBF @path = N'something', @name = N'something';` - but since you've declared `@sql` as a non-optional parameter, you need to pass that too. And as I commented below, `exec @sql` is problematic (and why is it AFTER the `END`?) - you want `exec(@sql);` or `exec sp_executesql @sql;`. See https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql and also https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix

Comment: @Aaron, yes I did mean `DECLARE` thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you want to define `@sql` as a local variable in the stored procedure, not a parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE readDBF (
  @path nvarchar(1000),
  @name nvarchar(50)
) AS
BEGIN
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    set @sql = 'select * from openrowset(''VFPOLEDB.1'', ''' + @path +'''; ''; '', ''select * from ''' + @name + ''')';
    exec(@sql);
END;
```

If you are learning about dynamic SQL, you should be learning to use `sp_executesql` rather than just `exec`.